In structs, why is initializing to 0 not allowed but initializing to 1 is valid code
#include <stdio.h>
        
struct temp{
    unsigned int zero_bit : 1;
    unsigned int first_bit : 1;
};
        
//   struct temp_1{
//       unsigned int zero_bit : 0;
//       unsigned int first_bit : 0;
//   } ;    // Code fails
       
int main() {
     
    struct temp a1;
    printf("%d", a1.zero_bit); // returns 0
        
    return 0;
}

Why does struct temp1 fail but not struct temp, considering they are both initialized to 0.
Why does the compiler give me the false hope that zero_bit has been initialised to a value of 1 when it has been initialized to a value of 0 in reality?

The number is not initialization, that's saying how many bits each member of the bit-field will have. For temp_1 you say that zero_bit and first_bit will have zero bits. Which makes no sense. You might want to refresh the section of your beginners books or tutorials and what they say about bit-fields.

Also note that the variable a1 is not initialized, and its members will have indeterminate values.

See: Bit-fields.

The number after the : is not an initialization value, but rather the width (in bits) of a bit-field:

Bit-fields
Declares a member with explicit width, in bits. Adjacent bit-field
members may be packed to share and straddle the individual bytes.
identifier (optional) : width

Also from the documentation link above:

width -
an integer constant expression with a value greater or equal
to zero and less or equal the number of bits in the underlying type.
When greater than zero, this is the number of bits that this bit-field
will occupy. The value zero is only allowed for nameless bit-fields
and has special meaning: it specifies that the next bit-field in the
class definition will begin at an allocation unit's boundary.

(emphasis is mine)
In struct temp width of 1 is valid, but in struct temp_1 a width of 0 isn't valid (it does not fall under the exception of a nameless bit-field mentioned above).
This is the reason for the compilation error for struct temp_1.
Another issue is that in these lines:
struct temp a1;
printf("%d", a1.zero_bit); // returns 0

a1 is not initialized and therefore contains indetermined values. The value of 0 that you see is just by chance.
